# Extract values of a PDF form to a XML file using JS actions in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, pdf-form

I'm trying to get values of some specific form fields and then generate a XML file based on that data using JS actions when a user clicks a button in Adobe Acrobat. It's possible to get those values but I'm not sure how to generate that xml and provide it to the user.
I do check these documents but can't find anything related:

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/files/Doc.js.html

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/files/App.js.html

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/files/Util.js.html

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/files/Event.js.html

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Mobile/iosapi/files/Field.js.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be looking at the JS documentation for mobile Reader. Do you need this to work on mobile devices? If you do, it's not possible. You'll need to have the users fill the form in the Acrobat or Reader Desktop version to have access to the richer JavaScript functionality. If that's acceptable, I can add an answer showing how to do it.

Comment: That would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is "just an XML", you could export as XFDF, which is the XML representation of FDF, the Forms Data File.

Otherwise, you could create a (hidden) multiline text field, and assemble the XML, which you can then export.

Answer (score 1):

**Add** the following JavaScript to the Mouse Up event of your button.
[image]

```
this.exportAsXFDF();
```

The user will be prompted to date the data as an XFDF file which is XML.